# Conversion from string "FalseTrue" to type 'Boolean' is not valid issue

Tags: vb.net, string, winforms, if-statement, boolean

Conversion from string "FalseTrue" to type 'Boolean' is not valid. How can I fix it in this case? Label5.Text has to contain those, it can't equal as they provide the full converted time to EST including date.

```
If ((Label5.Text.Contains("8:00") Or Label5.Text.Contains("1:35")) & (Label5.Text.Contains("PM"))) Then
        WebControl1.Source = New Uri("http://www.flalottery.com/play4.do")
        Label1.Text = "Loading in 7 seconds..."
        Label2.Text = "Loading in 7 seconds..."
        Refresh.Start()
End If
```

Winforms VB.NET 2012 Express.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used the string concatenation operator `&` instead of the logical `And` operator:

```
If ((Label5.Text.Contains("8:00") Or Label5.Text.Contains("1:35")) And (Label5.Text.Contains("PM"))) Then
```

Comment: Thank you to you both. It's getting really late and I just noticed that.

Answer (score 2):

Use are using the VB [`&`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te2585xw.aspx) symbol which will join the two values, you want to use [`And`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdbcfyzh.aspx) instead

Comment: Thank you to you both. It's getting really late and I just noticed that.